# Error: Protocol requires a nested type '_BitsType' (Swift.FloatingPointType)

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to make one of my classes adopt the `FloatingPointProtocol`; I have implemented all of the required functions shown [here](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/FloatingPointType/), however Swift is still giving me the below error:

`Protocol requires a nested type '_BitsType'(Swift.FloatingPointType)`

I've been unable to find any documentation with regards to `_BitsType` and its nesting inside `FloatingPointType`. What do I need to implement in order to have my class successfully adopt `FloatingPointType`?

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_BitsType` is a type used to represent a floating point value as
"raw bits". The definition was [publicly visible in Swift 1.2](http://swiftdoc.org/v1.2/protocol/FloatingPointType/).
You can lookup the definition in the [Swift open source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointOperations.swift.gyb), or using the Swift REPL:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81). Type :help for assistance.
  1> :type lookup FloatingPointType
protocol FloatingPointType : Strideable {
  typealias _BitsType
  @warn_unused_result static func _fromBitPattern(bits: Self._BitsType) -> Self
  @warn_unused_result func _toBitPattern() -> Self._BitsType
...
```

Those two methods convert between the floating point value and
some integer type with the same bit pattern. For example, it is
`UInt32` for `Float`:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81). Type :help for assistance.
  1> :type lookup Float
...
extension Float : FloatingPointType {
  typealias _BitsType = Swift.UInt32
  static func _fromBitPattern(bits: Swift.Float._BitsType) -> Swift.Float
  func _toBitPattern() -> Swift.Float._BitsType
...
```

For your own floating point type you have to decide on a suitable
integer type which can represent the raw bits, and provide
the conversion functions. For a "short float" format this could 
for example be:

```
struct MyFloat : FloatingPointType {
    let value : UInt16

    func _toBitPattern() -> UInt16 {
        return value
    }
    static func _fromBitPattern(bits: UInt16) -> MyFloat {
        return MyFloat(value: bits)
    }

    // ....
}
```

*However,* both `_BitsType` and the conversion function are not
publicly visible in Swift 2 (or later) anymore and not officially
documented. That could indicate that implementing your own
floating point type is not supported and might not work as intended.